# tcl proc command not working while running file from shell

Tags: shell, tcl, ns2

I am new in programming and want to run my first code of tcl..The code is here

```
proc tempconv {} {

    set lower 0
    set upper 150
    set step 25
    set fahr $lower
    while {$fahr<$upper} {
        set celsius [expr 5*($fahr-32)/9]
        puts "Fahernheit/Celsius : $fahr/$celsius"
        incr fahr $step
                  }
          }
```

I have saved this to file test.tcl..The problem is when I try to run this using shell environment it does not show any result but when delete this proc statement and don't make any procedure then the result is shown..can any body tell me how to solve this problem. 
with proc statement the result is like this

```
muhammad@muhammad-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/ns-allinone-2.35$ ns test.tcl
muhammad@muhammad-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/ns-allinone-2.35$
```

without procedure the result is here

```
muhammad@muhammad-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ cd ns-allinone-2.35/
muhammad@muhammad-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/ns-allinone-2.35$ ns test.tcl
Fahernheit/Celsius : 0/-18
Fahernheit/Celsius : 25/-4
Fahernheit/Celsius : 50/10
Fahernheit/Celsius : 75/23
Fahernheit/Celsius : 100/37
Fahernheit/Celsius : 125/51
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the proc:

```
# Define a procedure called test
proc test {} {
   puts "Test Running"
}

# Call the procedure
test
```

Comment: thanks Jackson for you quick answer..the problem is still same..muhammad@muhammad-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/ns-allinone-2.35$ ns test.tcl
muhammad@muhammad-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/ns-allinone-2.35$...........it is not showing text Test running...

Comment: muhammad@muhammad-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/ns-allinone-2.35$ ns test.tcl
muhammad@muhammad-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/ns-allinone-2.35$ test
muhammad@muhammad-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/ns-allinone-2.35$ 
no result even by calling proc test..

Comment: if I directly write you code in ns environment in shell then it works but if I save this to a file and then run file from shell, it doesn't work..even if I call procedure..muhammad@muhammad-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ ns
% proc test {} {
   puts "Test Running"
}
% test
Test Running
%

Comment: When you say 'call file from the shell' what do you mean?  tclsh myfile.tcl or juts myfile.tcl.

Comment: I mean tclsh myfile.tcl

Answer (score 0):

```
proc procedure { } {
puts "XYZABC"
}
procedure
```

And in terminal go to

```
ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/
```

directory and then run

```
ns pathtoyourfile/filename.tcl
```